# How to change legend title and key order and colour to a multi-stacked barplot in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am working with R to a multi-stacked barplot and I would like to change the name of the legend and edit the colour of the variables in question (I would totally prefer a blue palette).

However, I have been trying to edit the legend and the colour in vain. I was wondering if you can help me out!

Below is the code I've used so far.

```
    library(ggthemes)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(reshape2)

    theme_set(theme_classic())


    multiBP <- data.frame(Countries = c('Romania','Hungary','Spain','Italy','poland','Greece','France','Finland','Germany','Denmark','Netherlands','Sweden'),

                          worried_emigration <- c(0.55, 0.39, 0.34, 0.32, 0.30, 0.28, 0.14, 0.14, 0.08, 0.06, 0.06, 0.04),

                          both <- c(0.26, 0.34, 0.38, 0.35, 0.30, 0.54, 0.31, 0.20, 0.29, 0.12, 0.15, 0.14),

                          immigration <- c(0.10, 0.2, 0.19, 0.24, 0.27, 0.07, 0.25, 0.44, 0.31, 0.53, 0.55, 0.47),

                          neitherdontknow <- c(0.09, 0.07, 0.09, 0.09, 0.13, 0.11, 0.30, 0.22, 0.32, 0.29, 0.24, 0.35))





    data.m <- melt(multiBP, id.vars='Countries')

    data.m['value'] <- data.m['value']*100


    levels(data.m$variable) <- c("% Worried about emigration", "% Worried both immigration and emigration",
                                 "% Worried about immigration", "% Neither / don't know")


    data.m$variable <- factor(data.m$variable, levels = c("% Worried about emigration", "% Worried about immigration",
                                                          "% Worried both immigration and emigration", "% Neither / don't know" ))



    # ggplot(arrange(mdat,variable,desc(value)), aes(variable, value, fill=day)) + 



    ag<-filter(data.m, variable == "% Worried about emigration")

    data.m$Countries <- factor(data.m$Countries, levels=ag$Countries[order(ag$value)], ordered = TRUE)



    # ggplot(arrange(mdat,variable,desc(value)), aes(variable, value, fill=day)) + 



    ggplot(arrange(data.m, variable, desc(value), Countries), aes(fill = forcats::fct_rev(variable), Countries, value))+
      geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity', colour='grey')+
      expand_limits(x=c(0,0))+
      coord_flip()+
      labs(title="Multiple Time Series Chart", 
           subtitle="BLA BLA ", 
           caption="Source: The Guardian")+
      # guide_legend(title=  'TItolo')+
      theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'grey90', size = 1, linetype='solid')) +
      geom_text(aes(label=paste0((value),"%")),
                position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),size=3)
```

That returns me:

[image]

Comment: See answer for legend title query. Could you can say what colours you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I've been thinking about an electric blue palette (from dark blue to the light one)

Comment: I hope you do not mind me suggesting that you might want to have a look at tidying your code there is quite a lot of clutter. I've rationalised the ggplot a bit and piped in the data frame as there is a lot going on here.

Comment: Yes, totally got your point. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: And a more accurate form of words for the question might be: "How do I change legend title,  key order and colour to a multi-stacked barplot  in R  with ggplot2" ;-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

arrange(data.m, variable, desc(value), Countries) %>% 
ggplot(aes(Countries, value, fill = fct_rev(variable)))+
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity' ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE), palette = "Blues") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value,"%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3)+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title = "Multiple Time Series Chart", 
       subtitle = "BLA BLA ", 
       caption = "Source: The Guardian",
       fill = "Legend Title")+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'grey90', size = 1, linetype='solid'))
```

Gives you:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for your prompt response, it worked. I had another question, do you also know how to reorder the colours shown in the legend in order to have them in the same order as the chart? Moreover, I would like to change the colours manually - I was thinking of a blue palette. Have you any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Thank you very much!! Lovely result!